# AWK, getline - remove the last field

Tags: awk, getline

I have a file:

```
Srednia ocen Wojciech Zieba: 3.83
Srednia ocen Jakub Pelc: 3.76
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak: 3.90
```

I want to improve the command:

1.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ while( getline $0 < "file") sub($NF,"",$0); print $0}' 
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak: 
userpc@userpc-desktop:~
```

2.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ while( getline a < "file") sub($NF,"", a); print a}' 
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak: 3.90 
userpc@userpc-desktop:~/Pulpit$
```

I have to do it by getline. My example is only part of the script. I want to remove last field and print the result:

```
Srednia ocen Wojciech Zieba: 
Srednia ocen Jakub Pelc: 
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak:
```

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

But this way does not print the remaining fields:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ while( getline a < "file") {sub(/[^:]*$/,"",a); print a, $1, $3}}'
Srednia ocen Wojciech Zieba:  
Srednia ocen Jakub Pelc:  
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak:  
bolek@bolek-desktop:~/Pulpit$
```

This command prints all the fields:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ while( getline $0 < "file") {sub($NF,"",$0); print $0, $1, $3}}'
Srednia ocen Wojciech Zieba:  Srednia Wojciech
Srednia ocen Jakub Pelc:  Srednia Jakub
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak:  Srednia Jan
bolek@bolek-desktop:~/Pulpit$
```

How to improve the first command? I want to first command also shared lines on the field.

**EDIT-1:**

I want to improve the command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ while( getline a < "file") {sub(/[^:]*$/,"",a); print a, $1, $3}}'
```

I want to print the result:

```
Srednia ocen Wojciech Zieba:  Srednia Wojciech
Srednia ocen Jakub Pelc:  Srednia Jakub
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak:  Srednia Jan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an awk way:

```
awk -F':' '$0=$1 ":"' file
```

**test**

```
kent$  echo "Srednia ocen Wojciech Zieba: 3.83
Srednia ocen Jakub Pelc: 3.76
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak: 3.90"|awk -F':' '$0=$1 ":"'
Srednia ocen Wojciech Zieba:
Srednia ocen Jakub Pelc:
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak:
```

**update**

i don't know what you really wanna do, but your while{} scope has problem. maybe you want this?

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{ while( getline $0 < "file") {sub($NF,"",$0); print $0}}' 
Srednia ocen Wojciech Zieba: 
Srednia ocen Jakub Pelc: 
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak:
```

if you want to introduce your own variable, say a, it has no idea about $NF. based on your example, you could do:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{ while( getline a < "file") {sub(/[^:]*$/,"",a); print a}}' 
Srednia ocen Wojciech Zieba:
Srednia ocen Jakub Pelc:
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak:
```

Comment: A good solution, but I have to do it by getline. My example is only part of the script.

Comment: A good solution, but how to improve this example?: `awk 'BEGIN{while(getline a < "file") sub($NF,"",a); print a}'`

Comment: @downvoter downvote is ok, but please explain a bit. I want to improve my awk knowledge. so please share your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

No need for awk, use cut and sed:

```
$ cat in.txt 
Srednia ocen Wojciech Zieba: 3.83
Srednia ocen Jakub Pelc: 3.76
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak: 3.90
$ cut -d: -f1 in.txt | sed 's/$/:/'
Srednia ocen Wojciech Zieba:
Srednia ocen Jakub Pelc:
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak:
```

Comment: A good solution, but I have to do it by getline. My example is only part of the script.

Answer (score 1):

As it is you set the `a` variable to each line in turn, but if you omit `a` `$0` will be set and auto-split will be performed, which would allow you to do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ while( getline < "file") { $NF = ""; print $0, $1, $3 } }'
```

Output:

```
Srednia ocen Wojciech Zieba:  Srednia Wojciech
Srednia ocen Jakub Pelc:  Srednia Jakub
Srednia ocen Jan Resiak:  Srednia Jan
```